# Solutions of $X^2+2=Y^3$ in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, gaussian-integers

The Mathematician James T. Cross, on his work "Primitive Pythagorean Triples of Gaussian Integers", displayed a method
for generating all Pythagorean triples in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$. Inspired by his work, I want to find all the gaussian integer solutions of the equation $X^2+2=Y^3$. In $\mathbb{Z}$, the only solution is $x=5,y=3$ or $x=-5,y=3$. A trivial solution in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ is $x=i$, $y=1$. My question is:

Any other mathematician solved this problem any time before?

Comment: You might find some interest in [following discussion](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/142220/fermats-proof-for-x3-y2-2).

Comment: are you asking if this is an open problem ? also I don't quite see the relationship between pythagorean triples over $\Bbb Z[i]$ and solutions of $X^2+2 = Y^3$.

Comment: For easy reference, the equation $X^2 + 2 = Y^3$ corresponds to elliptic curve `1728.o3` in LMFDB (Cremona label `1728v1`): http://www.lmfdb.org/EllipticCurve/Q/1728/o/3

Answer (score 1):

I apologize for interchanging $X$ and $Y$, but that makes me more comfortable. No matter what, this is fancy stuff, and is an example of how things that are relatively simple in the quadratic case suddenly become complicated or even intractable in the next case along the way.

You’re dealing with the elliptic curve $Y^2=X^3-2$, and asking for $\Bbb Z[i]$-integral points. The corresponding question for $\Bbb Z$-integral points is covered by Siegel’s Theorem, which says that any elliptic curve over $\Bbb Q$ has only finitely many $\Bbb Z$-points. This is a field that I know only by rumor, and there will certainly be people on MSE who know the field backwards and forwards, much as it can be known. I’d guess that Siegel can be (probably has been) generalized to this case too. This is certain: the $\Bbb Q(i)$-points of the curve form a commutative group that’s finitely generated, that’s the Mordell-Weil Theorem. Finding the generators is doable by fairly advanced methods, but not usually easy.

So your assignment is to go to the ever-reliable Wikipedia and look up elliptic curves, Siegel Theorem (on elliptic curves), and the Mordell-Weil Theorem.

Comment: Your Fueter’s elliptic $y^2=x^3-2$ is birrationally equivalent to the Selmer’s elliptic $X^3+Y^3= A$, where $A=\frac{\sqrt 6}{36}$, by the transformation
$$(x,y)\to \left(\frac{36A+y}{6x},\frac{36A-y}{6x}\right)$$ giving the curve $$ X^3+Y^3=\frac{\sqrt 6}{36}$$
Making $(X,Y)=(U\frac{\sqrt 6}{6},V\frac{\sqrt 6}{6})$ you get the Fermat cubic  $U^3+V^3=1$ which, as everybody knows, have not rational points (excepting the point at the infinite). But what is not well known is that this curve has infinitely many quadratic points. I wanted to say this last assertion.

Comment: @Piquito it's pretty easy to show that $y^2 = x^3-2$ has infinitely many quadratic points, simply pick any rational $x$ and then solve for $y$.

Comment: The tone of your comment, dear friend, I find inappropriate. I wanted to refer to non trivial quadratic points in the well known Fermat cubic emphasizing its near relation with the curve of this post. Why not make a comment on your trivial infinity of quadratic points in relation with Siegel’s theorem? The points that want to have the O.P. Camarillo are "integer", gaussian but integer and that could discern some doubts of Lubin maybe. It seems you can add something about it, don’t you?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the way of working directly on $\Bbb Z+\Bbb Z[i]$. But the equation in this ring of Gaussian integers is equivalent to the following system of four unknowns in $\Bbb Z$
$$\begin{cases}x^2-y^2+2=z^3-3zw^2\\2xy=3z^2w-w^3\end{cases}$$
 This allows us to find out some infinite sets of solutions. Making, for example, $z=w$ we have $$x^2-y^2+2=-2z^3\\2xy=2z^3$$ therefore
$$x^2-y^2+2+2xy=0\qquad (1)$$ We have in $(1)$ the particular solutions $(x,y)=(\pm1,\mp1),(\pm1,\mp3),(\pm7,\mp3)$

From this one has for $X=x+yi$ and $Y=z+wi$ the solutions of the proposed equation in Gaussian integers
$$(x,y,z,w)=(\pm1,\mp1,t,t),(\pm1,\mp3,t,t),(\pm7,\mp3,t,t)$$ where t is an arbitrary rational integer.